# Multiple Options Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a SharePoint list where when a new item is created the permissions are removed using Power Automate and then reassigned according to the facility using 'send an http request to SharePoint' and targeting one of the defined permission groups on the site. This works fine in test for 2 different facilities but for the actual version there are 12 different facilities and therefore 12 different permission groups. I know you can add different branches to a condition but understand there is a limit to this and it would be unwieldly to edit anyway. Is there a better way of writing the flow without 12 different branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Switch-case model which is a type of Condition in Power Automate.
Here is the article about Switch-case model:[Switch-case model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/use-conditionals#switch-case-model)